# What's the difference between static streaming and target textures in SDL?

Tags: opengl, rust, sdl-2

I can't find a proper description of the types of the texture. Documentation (https://docs.rs/sdl2/0.34.3/sdl2/render/struct.TextureCreator.html#method.create_texture) says about static, streaming and target textures, but gives a little information on how they differ.

If I want to update texture completely on each frame (the texture is 100% of the canvas in size), which texture should I use?

Comment: http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_TextureAccess

Comment: This article says 'static' is for 'rarely modified', but there is no other information (on difference between target and streamed).

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin It does say that a "target" texture can be used as a render target. If you don't know the meaning of that,  I'd suggest investing some time into looking up the "render to texture" concept.

Comment: Question is, how do you update the texture? With SDL drawing functions, or by manually writing pixels?

Comment: If you use an SDL renderer to change it, then you apparently must use `TARGET`. If you change pixels manually (with CPU, I mean), then `STREAMING`.

Answer (score 3):

It took me a bit of time to understand difference between them, but:

- Static texture is a texture which is rarely changed (like sprites).
- Target texture is a texture which can be used as a 'drawing place' (to be used as a surface, using SDL draw primitives). It's intended to be updated often.
- Streaming texture is a special type of texture which assumes a full update from external source of data. It was designed for video players and alike (render new frame of the video into the same texture). It's intended to be updated often too.

The streaming texture should be updated with `with_lock` method which takes closure to perform update. The closure gets the texture's writable byte-array as a parameter.

So, the key difference is that 'target' allows to 'draw' on the texture (fill, draw a line, bltbit, etc), and 'streaming' allows to update it as byte-array, (lower level even than pixel array).